# Parse HEX float

Tags: javascript, node.js, ieee-754

I have integer, for example, `4060`.

How I can get HEX float (`\x34\xC8\x7D\x45`) from it?

JS hasn't `float` type, so I don't know how to do this conversion.

Thank you.

Comment: I think I'm missing something obvious, but you have an integer; there is no decimal portion (except an implicit `0`). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Anyone who voted for "duplicate", please learn about IEEE 754 formats...voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer is no longer valid. `Buffer` has been deprecated (see https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_size).

New Solution:

```
function numToFloat32Hex(v,le)
{
    if(isNaN(v)) return false;
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var dv  = new DataView(buf);
    dv.setFloat32(0, v, true);
    return ("0000000"+dv.getUint32(0,!(le||false)).toString(16)).slice(-8).toUpperCase();
}
```

For example:

```
numToFloat32Hex(4060,true) // returns "00C07D45"
numToFloat32Hex(4060,false) // returns "457DC000"
```

Tested in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: `Buffer` hasn't been deprecated

Answer (score 7):

If you want a hex *string*, try this:

```
> var b = new Buffer(4);
> b.writeFloatLE(4060, 0)
> b.toString('hex')
'00c07d45'
```

And the other way (using your input):

```
> Buffer('34C87D45', 'hex').readFloatLE(0)
4060.5126953125
```

**UPDATE**: `new Buffer(size)` has been deprecated, but it's easily replaced by `Buffer.alloc(size)`:

```
var b = Buffer.alloc(4);
```

Comment: It can also read doubles in big or little endian. Thanks, very helpful.