# Convert hexadecimal to 32 float in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this function in php that would convert hexadecimal to 32 float in php. How do you do it in Javascript

```
public static function hexTo32Float($val)
{
    $packed=pack("H*",$val);
    $reversedpac=strrev($packed);
    $unpack=unpack( "f",$reversedpac);

    return array_shift($unpack);
}
```

Comment: well i have tried this which i found somewhere here but id didn't work. return parseInt("0x"+hexNumber);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting hexadecimal to float in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055723/converting-hexadecimal-to-float-in-javascript)

Comment: @DeepakBhattarai this is the same approach as my answer. What exactly was the error?

Comment: @Callahan if we convert 0x8c42465d the float should be around 49.something

Comment: @DeepakBhattarai Are you sure that `hexNumber` did not already contain a `0x` prefix? In that case the output would have been 0 for your input.

Comment: no it doesn't contain 0x

Comment: You still did not tell us what the result of the function is.

Comment: the result is in integer. 2353153715

Comment: Ah I see now. How dumb, sry. How could I expect a float value from a function called `parseInt`...

Comment: Mistake happens sometimes

Comment: Okay the problem here is that you would need to know the exact representation of your Hex number i.e. is it signed? and so on. You will be lucky if there is a ready to use function in javascript I think.

Comment: i hope i will find it

Comment: Please see [this question][1] and [this question][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055723/converting-hexadecimal-to-float-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a complete BS answer try the following I found in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612520/parse-hex-float) question:
`var b = new Buffer(hexNumber, 'hex').readFloatBE(0)`.
edit: The fault was the usage of readFloatLE here.
For further explanation: The point here is that `readFloatXX()` expects buffer contents as two's complement signed values. I guess `readFloatLE` is the version for unsigned floats (could not find that in the docs, though).

Comment: @DeepakBhattarai Please try this one. I undeleted my answer and dont know if you get notified for this.

Comment: I did this too, but it doesn't convert '42458c14' to 49.something which is what i need

Comment: @DeepakBhattarai There seems to be a `readFloatBE` version too. Maybe try that.

Comment: well that works fine. edit your answer so that i can mark you

Answer (score 2):

What about playing with TypedArray (that will only work with recent browsers) ?

```
var intData = Uint32Array(1);
intData[0] = parseInt("42458c14", 16);
var dataAsFloat = new Float32Array(intData.buffer);
var result = dataAsFloat[0];
// result == 49.38679504394531
```

EDIT (one year later ...) : It does seem that the result could depend on whether or not your CPU is big indian or little indian. Be careful when using this.

Comment: thanks this works too. but which one do  i choose @callahan's one or your?

Comment: Well this one is only a bit longer. You should just take the version that you like more to see in your code.

Comment: @callahan's answer uses the Buffer object which doesn't seems to be a part of html5. If you're doing it in a browser, you should prefer my version. If you're using Node.js, his solution is better.

Comment: I will keep both."Looks like i have to call two of the functions randomly"

Comment: The node.js thing is a good point. Never coded javascript, did not think of that.